# Disable VSCode file editor re-use

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, I can type a filename and open it.

Since some recent update, these files open in the same editor, so it isn't possible to open multiple files one after the other.

I remember there being a setting somewhere but I can't find it.  What's the name of it?  And/or, how do I change this behavior?

Comment: Are you opening the files in `preview` - the filenames look in italics?  If so, search for `[vscode] not preview` or similar.

Comment: @Mark That was it!  `workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen`.  Thanks!!  Do you mind posting as an answer?

Comment: Thanks, but I'll pass on posting it as an answer as there are a few duplicates already out there.

Comment: @Mark I haven't seen any, so I'll leave this here for now.  Perhaps future readers (or more than likely, myself) will find it useful.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark pointed out, the key word here is "preview".

Under Workbench -> Editor, there is Enable Preview from Quick Open.

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

Hopefully this helps someone else out who also doesn't know what the feature is called, and who is annoyed about VS Code constantly resetting their config when it feels like it.  :-)